# Display Date 1990-04-03 without alphabets

Tags: android

I want to display this date 1990-04-03 but instead I get Fri Apr 03 displayed

```
private static final String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd";
String date=jMemInfo.getString("dob");
SimpleDateFormat sdf= new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
Date dob=sdf.parse(date);
```

The bottom line is retrieving from the top

```
textDob.setText(String.valueOf(info.getDob().toString().substring(0,10)));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Date` is an instant in time and has no inherent format (beyond a `toString()`). To get the format you want you can use your `DateFormat` instance by changing this

```
textDob.setText(String.valueOf(info.getDob().toString().substring(0,10)));
```

to something with [`DateFormat.format(Date)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format%28java.util.Date%29) like

```
textDob.setText(sdf.format(info.getDob()));
```

Answer (score 0):

I am attaching a code which displays the selected date on button (A date dialog is opend when you click this button and displays selected date on it).

```
 private Button btnChangeDate;

    private int year;
    private int month;
    private int day;

    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 999;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

//Date Button Instance
        btnChangeDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.makepayact_btn_ChangeDate);

        //Date picker Dialog
        setCurrentDateOnView();
        addListenerOnButton();
}

// display current date
    public void setCurrentDateOnView() {
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // set current date into textView
        btnChangeDate.setText("Select");
    }

    //Button Listener
    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        btnChangeDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.makepayact_btn_ChangeDate);
        btnChangeDate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            // set date picker as current date
            return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, year, month,day);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {

            //getting current date instance
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int current_year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int current_month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int current_day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            year = selectedYear;
            month = selectedMonth;
            day = selectedDay;


                // set selected date into TextView
                btnChangeDate.setText(new StringBuilder().append(day)
                        .append("-").append(month + 1).append("-").append(year)
                        .append(" "));


        }
    };
```

you can get the date in string format, and later convert it to Date.

Let me know if this solves your problem. :)

Also, change the StringBuilder format if you want the format in yyyy-mm-dd.